# Python write lines to a UCS-2 LE BOM encoded text file

Tags: python, encoding, ucs2

I have an array of text strings in Python 3.7.

Now I want to write them all to a text file. The problem is, that textfile has to be in encoding UCS-2 LE BOM (thats what it says about its encoding in Notepad++), otherwise the file won't work in further processing.

How do I write the text strings to the file in that encoding while the strings staying readable?

```
    with open(textpath, "w", encoding='utf-16-le') as f:
    for line in newlines:
        f.write(line)
```

This does not work because it generates gibberish text...

Comment: Are you sure Notepad++ knows what it's doing? Have you tried writing an explicit BOM to the start? You know the difference between UCS-2 and UTF-16 (which should however not matter unless you are trying to use e.g. recent emoji characters outside of the Basic Multilingual Plane; and even then, the rest of the text should remain legible)?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show e.g. the first 10 or so bytes of the file as a hex dump, and tell us what text they are expected to represent? See also the [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info) for background and debugging tips.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing an explicit BOM:

```
with open(textpath, "w", encoding='utf-16-le') as f:
    f.write('\ufeff')
    for line in newlines:
        f.write(line)
        # Perhaps you also need to add a newline after each line?
        f.write('\n')
```

Obviously revert the last addition if your lines already have newlines.

Comment: Thanks, my file now is recognized as UCS2-LE but, now I have these two characters in the beginning of my file: ÿþ - they cannot be processed by the .exe and thus the system crashes? Usually, that file starts out with ¬

Comment: Sounds like you are examining the file with something which does not understand UCS-2. The request to clarify your question still holds.